# My Base Color texture map is not displaying the black part

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

The basecolor texture displays incorrectly. The **black** is missing.

[image: Black on texture isn 't showing up on model]

The blend file can be found here along with the maps..
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1he7iaioOuj2cvQ6nS4zlD6a1k2lvqWVN?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. my Subsurface slider was turned up too high..